Automapper - Map many-to-many intersect table property to flattened DTO class
Henlo!
First time working with AutoMapper and I'm trying to figure out why I'm not able to flatten a many-to-many relationship using an intersect table to a DTO object (API response in my case).
I'm trying to write a recipe management app where a recipe can have many ingredients and vice versa with the following models:
public class Recipe
{        
    public Guid RecipeId { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public TimeOnly PrepTime { get; set; }

    public TimeOnly CookTime { get; set; }

    public int Calories { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<Ingredient>? Ingredients { get; } = [];

    public ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; } = [];
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public Guid IngredientId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? Image { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Guid? UnitOfMeasurementId { get;set; }
    public virtual UnitOfMeasurement? UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Recipe>? Recipes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipesIngredient { get; } = [];
}

public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public Guid IngredientId { get; set; }      
    public Ingredient? Ingredient { get; set; }
    public Guid RecipeId { get; set; }      
    public Recipe? Recipe { get; set; }
    public Guid UnitOfMeasurementId { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasurement? UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

These base models need to be mapped to the following response classess:
public class RecipeResponse
{
    public Guid RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public TimeOnly PrepTime { get; set; }

    public TimeOnly CookTime { get; set; }

    public int Calories { get; set; }

    public string? Image { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IngredientResponse> Ingredients { get; } = [];
}

 public class IngredientResponse
 {
     public Guid IngredientId { get; set; }

     public string? Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public string? Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public string? Image { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public decimal Amount { get; set; }

     public UnitOfMeasurementResponse? UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }        
 }

I have used the following mappings but I'm unable to map the "Amount" value from the RecipeIngredients table into my ICollection entities.
public RecipeMappings()
{    
    CreateMap<Recipe, RecipeResponse>();     
}

public IngredientMappings() { 
    CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientResponse>()
        .ForMember(x => x.UnitOfMeasurement, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.UnitOfMeasurement));
    CreateMap<RecipeIngredient, IngredientResponse>()                
        .ForMember(x => x.UnitOfMeasurement, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.UnitOfMeasurement))
        .ForMember(x=> x.Amount, y => y.MapFrom(z=> z.Amount));
}

public RecipeIngredientMappings()
{
    CreateMap<RecipeIngredient, IngredientResponse>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IngredientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ingredient!.IngredientId))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount));
    
    CreateMap<Recipe, RecipeResponse>()
        .ForMember(x=> x.Ingredients, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.RecipeIngredients));
}

The code responsible for retrieving the entities is the following:
public async Task<IEnumerable<Recipe>> GetAll()
{
    return await _context.Recipes.Include(r=> r.Ingredients).ThenInclude(ri => ri.UnitOfMeasurement).ToListAsync();
}


And applying the mapping in the API:
public async Task<ActionResult<RecipeResponse>> GetRecipeById(Guid RecipeId)
{
    try
    {
        Recipe? r = await _recipeService.GetRecipe(RecipeId);

        if (r != null) { 
        
            RecipeResponse resp = _mapper.Map<RecipeResponse>(r);
            return Ok(resp);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Data that I receive in the front-end is not including the amount as can be seen in the example below: (Amount is 0 where it's 1 in the database)
    [
      {
        "recipeId": "735bf5ff-e4c2-4c2c-b5a3-71361243d5a5",
        "name": "Pasta Salt and Pepper",
        "description": "Pasta Salt and Pepper",
        "prepTime": "00:05:00.0000000",
        "cookTime": "00:05:00.0000000",
        "calories": 0,
        "image": "saltandpepper.jpg",
        "ingredients": [
          {
            "ingredientId": "bc8facb3-3c23-4879-bb4f-13e9176be330",
            "name": "Pepper",
            "description": "Black Pepper",
            "image": "pepper.jpg",
            "amount": 0,
            "unitOfMeasurement": {
              "unitOfMeasurementId": "15288c4d-0b83-4a5e-8b77-198e64f639a3",
              "name": "Tablespoon"
            }
          },
          {
            "ingredientId": "9183f94a-4646-46d7-b174-49e4f92fff29",
            "name": "Salt",
            "description": "Table Salt",
            "image": "salt.jpg",
            "amount": 0,
            "unitOfMeasurement": {
              "unitOfMeasurementId": "15288c4d-0b83-4a5e-8b77-198e64f639a3",
              "name": "Tablespoon"
            }
          }
      }
    ]

Long story short.... help? I'm smashing my head against my screen but I can't seem to wrap my head around merging the many to many relationship into a "simple" response class which combines them.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?
